# how to get only date from varchar2 string and compare another date using oracle 9i statement?

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

ex.

i want to compare date from string 'web_data_update-09-Dec-2016_12:44:14' with another date like this:

**Note**: my dataupdon field have value like 'web_data_update-09-Dec-2016_12:44:14'.

```
select * from mytable where to_char(dataupdon,'dd-Mon-yyyy')<>'31-Dec-1899';
```

Comment: Is data in `dataupdon` column in always same format like `web_data_update-<DD-MON-YYYY_HH24:MI:SS>` ??

Comment: I see that the question is still opened. If you are satisfied with any of the answer, then `accept` it, so the question could be closed. Read [What to do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Also close your previous questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are comparing on dates and ignoring the time component then you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  dataupdon NOT LIKE '%31-Dec-1899%';
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         dataupdon,
         '\d{2}-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}'
       ) <> '31-Dec-1899';
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  TO_DATE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           dataupdon,
           '\d{2}-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}',
           1,  -- Start from the first character
           1,  -- Get the first occurrence
           'i' -- Case insensitive
         ),
         'DD-Mon-YYYY'
       ) <> DATE '1899-12-31';
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  SUBSTR( dataupdon, INSTR( dataupdon, '-' ) + 1, 11 ) <> '31-Dec-1899';
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, REGEX were not supported by oracle 9i, right?

Comment: @Utsav Missed that hidden in the title. I've retagged the question to make it clearer. You are correct that the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` queries will only work in 10g and later but the other two options should work in 9i.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Corrected as per MT0.

This will work only if `dataupdon` is a string where first `11` characters of last `20` characters are in format `DD-MON-YYYY` like your example ( web_data_update-***09-Dec-2016***_12:44:14 )

If they are not, then it will not work.

```
select * from my_table
where 
to_date(substr(dataupdon,-20,11),
        'DD-MON-YYYY'
        )
<> 
to_date('31-Dec-1899','DD-Mon-YYYY') --replace date inside with any date
```

Comment: This will not match unless the time component of `dataupdon` is `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an assumption that last two characters in the field store the date and used below query

```
create  table mytable(dataupdon varchar2(1000));
insert into mytable(dataupdon ) values ('web_data_update-09-Dec-2016_12:44:14');
commit;
select * from mytable where to_date(substr(dataupdon,-20,11),'DD-Mon-YYYY')<>to_date('31-Dec-1899','DD-Mon-YYYY');
select * from mytable where to_date(substr(dataupdon,-20,11),'DD-Mon-YYYY')<>to_date('09-Dec-2016','DD-Mon-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of MTO's last one query i have modified my query and got answer which i want.its here :

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE SUBSTR( dataupdon, INSTR(dataupdon,'-') -2,11 )<> upper('31-Dec-1899');`